# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using

```
document.querySelector("input[name='txtID']").value = "myid";
         document.querySelector("input[name='txtUserName']").value = "myname";
         document.querySelector("input[name='txtPassword']").value = "mypassword";
         document.querySelector("input[name='txtMode']").value = "1";
         document.querySelector("input[name='txtLang']").value = "en";
         document.querySelector("input[name='submit']").submit();
```

but i was got an error TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'document.querySelector("input[name='submit']").

and this is the HTML code :

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="set-loginbx-active" id="b2b">
                    <form name="form1" method="post" onSubmit="return HC.checkMode(this);">
                        <div id="lyAgent">
                            <div class="lbl-login" id="dAgentID">Agent Id.</div>
                            <div class="inp-login"><input name="txtID" id="txtID" type="text"></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="lbl-login" id="dUserName">Username</div>
                        <div class="inp-login"><input name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" type="text"></div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="lbl-login" id="dPassword">Password</div>
                        <div class="inp-login">
                            <input name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" type="password">
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtMode" id="txtMode" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtLang" id="txtLang" value="en" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="btn-login"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="LOGIN" /></div>
                        <div class="box-access">
                            <div class="tt-access">Access Level</div>
                            <div class="lnk-access"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" onclick="HC.loginMode(1);"> Master Login</div>
                            <div class="lnk-access"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" checked onclick="HC.loginMode(0);"> Agent Login</div>
                        </div>       
                    </form>
                </div>
```

can someone explain to me why ?

Comment: Try `input[type="submit"]`. Also add corresponding HTML cod.e

Comment: still not work @Tushar

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't call submit() on an `<input>`. That is a method of the `<form>`. Do this instead

```
document.querySelector("form[name='form1']").submit();
```

Edit: you should not have any element with a name 'submit'. In your HTML, your submit input also has the name submit. Remove the `name='submit'` attribute from the `<input>` element.

Comment: this is my html code : 
<div class="btn-login"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="LOGIN" /></div>

Comment: Replace that line with

`document.querySelector("form[name='form1']").submit();`

Comment: I got an error 
TypeError: HTMLInputElement is not a constructor (evaluating 'document.querySelector("form[name='form1']").submit()')

Comment: @Herdy That is because you name your submit button as submit.

Replace this

 `<div class="btn-login"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="LOGIN" /></div>`

With this

 `<div class="btn-login"><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" /></div>` and it should all work

Answer (score 0):

That should probably be:

```
document.querySelector("input[name=submit]").click()
```